# BinaryFormatter has been deprecated, how to deserialize entire object graph from json

Tags: json, dom, deserialization

update:
In newtonsoft, it works fine like this.

```
var saveObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

var root2 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Node>(saveObject);
```

Here, the entire "tree"/graph is reloaded into root2. Is this behaviour accomplishable with System.Text.Json?

original question:
I have a data model (more precisely a DOM) where I have been using BinaryFormatter to serialize and deserialize the entire graph of connected various objects. It has worked flawless for years. Now, the binaryFormatter has been deprecated, and Microsoft appears to suggest that one should use Json for the job.

Using System.Text.Json serializing the dom, the entire graph is serialized easily, however, when deserializing, only the root level node is deserialized. Any objects hanging on the root node is not deserialized. What am I missing to reload the entire graph? Annotations on the list property? Could anyone guide me to a good example? Or, any other good suggestions to save a dom on disc? Thank you.

```
using System.Text.Json;

var root = new Node("root");

var a1 = new Node("a1");
var a2 = new Node("a2");

var b11 = new Node("b11");
var b12 = new Node("b12");

var b21 = new Node("b21");
var b22 = new Node("b22");

root.Nodes.Add(a1);
root.Nodes.Add(a2);

a1.Nodes.Add(b11);
a1.Nodes.Add(b12);

a2.Nodes.Add(b21);
a2.Nodes.Add(b22);

var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true, };

string saveFile = JsonSerializer.Serialize(root,options);

Console.WriteLine("Savefile:");
Console.WriteLine(saveFile);


var loadFile = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Node>(saveFile,options)!;

Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("Loadfile:");
Console.WriteLine(loadFile);

public class Node
{
    public Node(string name)
    {
        Name = name;        
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Node> Nodes { get; set; } = new List<Node>();
}
```

Output:

```
Savefile:
{
  "Name": "root",
  "Nodes": [
    {
      "Name": "a1",
      "Nodes": [
        {
          "Name": "b11",
          "Nodes": []
        },
        {
          "Name": "b12",
          "Nodes": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Name": "a2",
      "Nodes": [
        {
          "Name": "b21",
          "Nodes": []
        },
        {
          "Name": "b22",
          "Nodes": []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Loadfile:
Node
```